# Mac Catalyst: Is it possible to set a scene to Active?

Tags: ios, scene, mac-catalyst

I have an Catalyst app with several independent scenes which can be open (foreground) at once.
Some scenes have buttons or other controls which will open (activate, give focus to, if not currently foreground) a different scene. If the target scene is already foreground (visible, but not frontmost), I want the target scene to be active.  **Is this possible?**

If I call UIApplication.shared.requestSceneSessionActivation on a scene that is already foreground, it opens a second copy of the target window, not activating the existing target.  The options available in requestSceneSessionActivation do not seem to allow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a reference to the UIWindowScene? requestSceneSessionActivation is what you want, passing in the scene like so: `requestSceneSessionActivation(scene, userActivity: nil, options: nil)`

Comment: Thanks foray  the suggestion @Adam, but if you read my Q, when I do what you suggest, it opens a second copy of the window, not simply giving focus to the original window already visible on the screen.  I am just now playing with the DYNAMIC lib which should give me access to the NSWindow methods.

Comment: Dynamic is great, but I’m using requestSceneSessionActivation in my app and it totally works, regardless of whether the scene is active or not. Are you sure the scene object you’re passing in is legit? passing either nil or an inactive scene will result in a new window of whatever your default config is.

Comment: I tried your suggestion to use requestSceneSessionActivation again in a clean experimental setting and it does work. Going back to my original code where it instead opened a copy of the scene, the difference was that in the original, I was passing a non-nil userActivity.   Using nil makes it work as desired.  The Apple dox on this point are extremely deficient (as usual I suppose)